# I have a pdf file that consists of multi-pages and I want to read it on Matlab as image, where each page to be represented as an image

Tags: matlab, pdf, image-processing

I have a PDF file that consists of multi-pages and I want to read it on Matlab as  image, where each PDF page to be read as an image. The PDF file is a scanned file of a questionnaire and I want to extract info from that. I can do it if I have  (png,jpeg,...) files but it is necessary for PDF.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're probably better of using [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to convert.

Comment: It seems good, but I want to import pdf and Ghostscript is mostly of exporting pdf files. So is there any other opportunity of reading pdf as image and then working on that image.

Comment: [GhostScript can convert a PDF file to an image file](http://superuser.com/questions/243461/how-to-convert-a-multi-page-pdf-file-to-png-files-with-one-png-file-per-page-of). Why would I have suggested it otherwise?

Comment: There is no such thing with matlab and the development of this kind of tool is complicated. As @excaza said I recommend to use an external application (Ghostscript is perfect). Don't forget that you can call an external application via the command `system`. So for example `system('gs ...')`